# write.csv with single quotes instead of double quotes

Tags: r

I want to output a csv file with write.csv in R, but instead of double quotes `"`, I want to use single quotes `'`.

Any idea?

Comment: What you mean if sinle quotes? Can you give a sample of what you've tried so far?

Comment: example: 'blub', 'blah', 'blubber', 4711 instead of
"blub", "blah", "blubber", 4711

Comment: I don't see a way to do this with `write.csv()`. A horrible hack, if your data set is small enough and you don't have embedded quotes, would be to capture the output of `write.csv()`; use `chartr()` to convert quotes; and `writeLines()` ...

Comment: What is the reason for using the non-standard single quotes to surround string column values?

Comment: Surprisingly not even `data.table::fwrite` supports setting another quote character :-(

Comment: @RYoda to match the input format of another process.

Answer (score 1):

In the meantime I came up with the following workaround:

```
table <- table %>% 
  mutate_if(is.character, function(x) gsub("'", " ", x)) %>% 
  mutate_if(is.character, function(x) paste0("'", x, "'"))

write.csv(table, file = "file.csv", quote=F, na = "", row.names = F)
```